# Use "to look forward" in kind of a negative sense

Tags: grammar, negation

About a week ago, I had a written test in English, and it was about a story we had to answer questions about. The story was about a kid, who got bullied at his old school, but he moved away with his parents, and will visit another school, he's anxious about getting bullied again, but happy about leaving his old school. Now one of the questions was: "Is he looking forward to his new school?", and I answered with yes, explaining, that his new school will be better than the old school, even if he is a bit worried. Now my English teacher marked that as wrong, because of the fact that he's afraid, that stuff could go wrong. Now my question is, can you actually use "to look forward" only in a positive sense, or could you also use it, like I thought, in the context of "to not look back"? It's not about that point in the test, I am just curious.

Comment: In principle you have a point. In certain circumstances, if the past was *definitely* bad, even though the future might look scary and unpromising, you might feasibly say something like ***I must look** [forward] **to the future*** (put the past behind me and move on). But it's *extremely* unlikely you'd include the word "forward" in that situation, because ***to look forward to** [something in the future]* has become an established idiomatic usage with the "positive" sense of ***eagerly anticipate some desired future***.

Comment: (But I support your teacher's downmark. Just because *in theory* you could stretch a point to justify your answer doesn't alter the fact that *in practice* the established idiom is how everyone uses these words.)

Comment: You can only **look forward to** in a positive sense. That phrase is NEVER used in a negative sense, because no-one looks forward to unpleasant, uncomfortable, etc things. It's not about future events as much as it is about **positive anticipation**.